# How to make third level haar transformation on an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, haar-wavelet

I have problem how to make third level on an image in Matlab. I use this code:

```
image=imread('image.jpeg');
wavename = 'haar';
[cA,cH,cV,cD] = dwt2(im2double(image),wavename); %first level 
[cAA,cAH,cAV,cAD] = dwt2(cA,wavename); % Recompute Wavelet of Approximation Coefs.
Level2=[cAA,cAH; cAV,cAD]; %contacinat and second level
imshow([Level2,cH; cV,cD],'Colormap',gray);

[cAAA,cAAH,cAAV,cAAD] = dwt2(cAA,wavename); % Recompute Wavelet of Approximation Coefs.
Level3=[cAAA,cAAH;cAAV,cAAD]; %contacinat
imshow([Level3, cAH; cAV,cAD],'Colormap',gray); %3 level
```

But the program says that there is an error in the last row. The error is "CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent." So the question is how can i make this code to work?

Comment: Where is the error. Please, always provide full information.

Comment: imshow([Level3, cAH; cAV,cAD],'Colormap',gray); %3 level
In this row is the error! The program says that 'CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent"

Comment: And they are not, are they. Check the sizes of each of those variables.

Comment: They are not, but i don't know how to check them and correct them.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your image, I assume.

The following code works properly, no changes made but the image

```
image=imread('cameraman.tif');
wavename = 'haar';
[cA,cH,cV,cD] = dwt2(im2double(image),wavename); %first level 
[cAA,cAH,cAV,cAD] = dwt2(cA,wavename); % Recompute Wavelet of Approximation Coefs.
Level2=[cAA,cAH; cAV,cAD]; %contacinat and second level
imshow([Level2,cH; cV,cD],'Colormap',gray);
figure
[cAAA,cAAH,cAAV,cAAD] = dwt2(cAA,wavename); % Recompute Wavelet of Approximation Coefs.
Level3=[cAAA,cAAH;cAAV,cAAD]; %contacinat
imshow([Level3, cAH; cAV,cAD],'Colormap',gray); %3 level
```

Comment: Hello! I've tried this code but it's not what i want. The result is only the second level of haar transformation and it doesn't include the third level :(

Comment: @MilenaBundeva this is the code you provided, I did not change anything...................

Comment: Yes, i know that

Comment: @MilenaBundeva So... you provided code that you wanted help with, but actually it was not the code you wanted? Also, you may need to rethink you variable names, as if `Level3` is not the third level, well, it has a terrible name

Comment: Yes, I want some help how to make  with my code third level of haar transformation.